# Creating Plot from multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to create plots from multiple columns. the data frame is given below. Positive and negative should be the multiple bars where as the model needs to be x

Data frame:

```
            Model Positive Negative
0            RNNs       99        1
1     Naive Bayes       22       38
2   Random Forest       51        9
3  SVM Classifier       40       20
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Many Thanks

Comment: Which kinds of plot are you looking for?

Comment: @JonathanBesomi Thanks for commenting. A bar graph which will have 2 bars for these 4 models in one graph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your data:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Model':['RNNs','Naive Bayes','Random Forest', 'SVM Classifier'], 
                        'Positive':[99,22,51,40], 
                        'Negative':[1,38,9,20]})
```

Plot:

```
df.set_index('Model')[['Positive','Negative']].plot.bar()
```

[image: barplot]

Comment: I want positive and negative in one graphs with showing 4 models results separately. thanks

Comment: Do you mean like that?

Answer (score 0):

Another way using seaborn and df.melt

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Model':['RNNs','Naive Bayes','Random Forest', 'SVM Classifier'], 
                        'Positive':[99,22,51,40], 
                        'Negative':[1,38,9,20]})
df = df.melt('Model', var_name='cols',  value_name='vals')
g = sns.factorplot(x="Model", y="vals", hue='cols', data=df,kind='bar')
g.set_xticklabels(rotation=90)
```

[image]